# The Fate of the Asgardians on the ship

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, thor-ragnarok

How did the Asgardians survive? I've been trying to noodle this through for a while now after seeing *Avengers: Endgame*. At the End of *Thor: Ragnarok*, the Asgardians are all on Thor's ship looking for new lands.

At the beginning of *Infinity War*, Thanos attacks the ship and comes aboard. There's been a slaughter and only a few Asgardians are left. Those are either killed directly by Thanos (Helmdal, Loki) or, well, basically Thor, who is picked up by the Guardians of the Galaxy.

In *Endgame* we find out that there are some Asgardians still alive,

> including Valkyrie, the Rock guy, and presumably enough to populate a town.

Where did they all come from? How'd they survive? Did I miss an explanation?

**Edit**: To be clear, in addition to whatever other Asgardians there might be in the universe (which might have been 50% decimated with the snap), I'm asking about the Asgardians on the ship at the end of Thor Ragnarok.

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed your answer, but this link answers it.

Answer (score 2):

Every planet and place Thanos went before acquiring the infinity gems, he left 50% of the population alive, that applies to Thor's ship as well.

Those Asgardians alive were part of the 50% that Thanos spared, and they escaped to earth with Valkyrie.

The details of how they reached the Earth are not mentioned in the movie, I imagine Thor's ship had some kind of escape vessel or smaller ship inside it.

Comment: Well yeah, but how did they get from the spaceship to Earth? The ship was pretty much wrecked and at the beginning of IW it seems like Thanos and the Black Order are killing anyone on sight

Comment: @Jenayah Those details we do not have, I imagine Thor's ship had some kind of escape vessel or smaller ship...

Comment: Valkyrie was on the ship with Thor - did I miss some scene where 1/2 Thor's crew departed for Earth?

Comment: Where was this escape ship mentioned in the movies?